# how to change nested user controls dynamicaly (non- mvvm)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I got this app that has dropdown menu which changes the big user controls (BW1) that consist of lots of small identical user controls. Now I transfered all the usercontrols to one dll (before I had this semi resolved with skins). So this is the big user control:

```
 <UserControl 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1" x:Class="WpfControlLibrary1.BW1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="1028" d:DesignWidth="1280">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SUC" TargetType="{x:Type local:SW1}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,2"/>

    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d11" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d10" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d01" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d02" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d03" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d04" Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d05" Grid.Column="5" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d06" Grid.Column="6" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d07" Grid.Column="7" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d08" Grid.Column="8" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d09" Grid.Column="9" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d12" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d13" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d14" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d15" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d16" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d17" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d18" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d19" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d20" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d21" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d22" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d23" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d24" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d25" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d26" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d27" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d28" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d29" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d30" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d31" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d32" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d33" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d34" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d35" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d36" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d37" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d38" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d39" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d40" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d41" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d42" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d43" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d44" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d45" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d46" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d47" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d48" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d49" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d50" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d51" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d52" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d53" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d54" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d55" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d56" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d57" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d58" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d59" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d60" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d61" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d62" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d63" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d64" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d65" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d66" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d67" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d68" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d69" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d70" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d71" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d72" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d73" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d74" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d75" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d76" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d77" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d78" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d79" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d80" Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d81" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d82" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d83" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d84" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d85" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d86" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d87" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d88" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d89" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d90" Grid.Row="9" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d91" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d92" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="9" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d93" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="9" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d94" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="9" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d95" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="9" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d96" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="9" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d97" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="9" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d98" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="9" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>
    <local:SW1 x:Name="d99" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="9" Style="{StaticResource SUC}" Stroke="red"/>

</Grid>
```

Now I want to change dynamicaly small user controls SW1 to SW2 or SW3 (all from the same dll) without the layout changing. Now is there any way I could do this without remaking the whole app in mvvm?

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use MVVM, you can name your `Grid` and then swap out the controls from your code behind:

```
<Grid Name="YourGrid" Background="Black">
    ...
</Grid>
```

Then in code behind:

```
// Repeat as necessary
YourGrid.Children.RemoveAt(indexOfControlToRemove);
SW2 sw2 = new SW2();
sw2.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
sw2.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 2);
YourGrid.Children.Add(sw2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that would kind of defeat the purpose of the dll as I wanted it to be so you can just add new user controls and the same principle would apply to all, but this way id have to write specific replacement code for each element and each version and it would also take forever to load when changing...